# dotnetzip and comma separated files

Tags: c#, csv, dotnetzip

I'm developing a console application with dot net that reads 7zip compressed csv files, and load csv file into a DB. It works well with tab separator, with special characters, but if the file has the "comma" separator, there is an error message "Bad signature".

The code is below:

```
        string DirPath = "myPath/myFolder";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(DirPath);
        FileInfo[] FileList = dir.GetFiles("*.7z", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var fileZip in FileList)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(fileZip.FullName))
                {
                    var a = zip.Entries.Where(p => p.FileName.EndsWith(".txt") || p.FileName.EndsWith(".csv")).ToList();
```

In the portion of code above, the error "bad signature" is thrown on the using statement, and only if the compressed file has a comma separator. 
Do you have any suggestion? Have you never ever face anything like that?
Thanks in advance for your support!
Cheers!

Comment: We use the same library also with CSV-files and we do not have any signature issues. Sure the file is valid and the zip is not corrupt?

Comment: Can you open the zip file in another zip utility like 7-zip? How do you write the file?

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your instant answers. The file is created by myself and right now it is a txt file that contains "hello,how,are,you", and it is zipped as 7z file. I write the file using notepad editor.

Comment: How do you write the zip file, I meant.

Comment: I use 7-zip File Manager.